# How Do I Reference a Datasource with JNDI using Spring's jee Tags

Tags: spring-mvc, jndi, geronimo

I have a datasource defined in my Geronimo server called LocalMysql. I can use the Geronimo admin console to query the database, and get data back, so I know it's at least configured correctly on the application server.

My next step was to create a Spring MVC Project in Eclipse. Taking nothing more than the template-generated code, I added the following lines to my servlet-context.xml.

In the "beans" declaration:

```
<beans ... xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="...
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd"
```

Then, in the body of the file, added:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="mysqlDatasource" jndi-name="LocalMysql"/>
```

What else do I need to make the connection?

***EDIT WITH UPDATE***

In addition to the  tag listed below in web.xml, I've added the following to the geronimo-web.xml:

```
<dep:dependency>
  <dep:groupId>console.dbpool</dep:groupId>
  <dep:artifactId>LocalMysql</dep:artifactId>
  <dep:version>1.0</dep:version>
  <dep:type>car</dep:type>
</dep:dependency>
```

as well as:

```
<name:resource-ref>
  <name:ref-name>LocalMysql</name:ref-name>
  <name:resource-link/>
</name:resource-ref>
```

Even with these addition, I am still getting the following exception:

```
Unable to resolve resource reference 'java:comp/env/LocalMysql' 
(Could not find resource ''.  Perhaps it has not yet been configured, 
or your application does not have a dependency declared for that 
resource module?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/yourresource"
        expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" resource-ref="true" />
```

And a reference in your `web.xml`:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/yourresource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Comment: I added the reference in my web.xml file, but got an error indicating I should add a resource reference to geronimo-web.xml. I did that, then got the error listed above.